# How to pass Image object as props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I need to pass in an Image object from the  page down to a  component which calls a  component for each image.

`Home() -> ThreePanel() -> Panel()`

From my understanding of props, this should be possible with the passing of props from ThreePanel to Panel.

But there is an error:

> Server Error
> Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass  "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {"height":"170em"}

This is what is the source of the error is.  I need to specify a specific object.  But as a template, I'd like to use a variable.

```js
<Image src={props.cardData.icon} // <-- Doesn't let me specify generic variable 
           height="170em"/>
```

```js
<Image src={props.cardData.icon.firstImage}
           height="170em"/>
```

I'm using Next JS.

Here's the full code below:

### Home.js

```js
import ThreePanel from '../components/threePanel'

import firstImage from '../public/images/one.png'
import secondImage from '../public/images/two.png'
import thirdImage from '../public/images/three.png'


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ThreePanel
          panelOne = {{ icon: {firstImage}, name: "First" }}
          panelTwo = {{ icon: {secondImage}, content: "Second" }}
          panelThree = {{ icon: {thirdImage}, content: "Third" }}>
    </ThreePanel>
  )
}
```

### threePanel.js

```js
import Panel from '../components/panel'

export default function ThreePanel(props) {
  return (
    <Grid container>
        <Grid item>
          <Panel cardData={props.firstImage.icon}></Panel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Panel cardData={props.secondImage.icon}></Panel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Panel cardData={props.thirdImage.icon}></Panel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

### panel.js

```js
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Panel(props) {
  return (
    <Image src={props.cardData} // <-- Doesn't let me specify generic variable 
           height="170em"/>
  )
}
```

Comment: `icon.emailImage` is not valid. The only properties that would be on `icon` are `firstImage`, `secondImage`, or `thirdImage`.

Comment: `props.cardData.icon.emailImage` is undefined. I suggest passing the image value directly on the `props.cardData.icon` prop. This avoids the odd nested property naming.

Comment: Sorry!  That was my mistake.  Variables have been updated.

Comment: @DrewReese Do you mean then the imports (`import firstImage from '../public/images/one.png'`) would be in `threePanel.js`?

Comment: No, import location is fine IMO, I was referring to passing the images on a consistently named prop, like `icon`. It's a bit unclear where `ThreePanel` is rendered though, and what props are passed around. Is `TripleCard ` supposed to be `ThreePanel` in `Home`?

Comment: My bad, TripleCard should be ThreePanel.  Sorry again, I was up late working on this.

Comment: @DrewReese It works!! I removed the nested prop `panelOne = {{ icon: {firstImage}, name: "First" }}` and turned it into 

`<ThreePanel cardOneIcon = {firstImage} cardTwoIcon = {secondImage} cardThreeIcon = {thirdImage}></ThreePanel>`

From there I was able to handle the image objects down the components.  Thank you so much @DrewReese!!  If you turn this into an answer, I'll mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`props.firstImage.icon` isn't defined in the `ThreePanel` component as the image was passed as `panelOne={{ icon: {firstImage}, name: "First" }}`. This means the child component would need to access `props.panelOne.icon.firstImage` to get to the image. This *may* work if each `Panel` component is passed the correctly nested property.

```
<Panel cardData={props.panelOne.icon.firstImage} />
<Panel cardData={props.panelTwo.icon.secondImage} />
...etc...
```

As you can see, each child panel needs to know which panel it is, but also needs to know what the image property was named. This isn't ideal.

## Solution

You should strive to pass consistently named props down to "repeated" children as each "instance" won't be aware which dynamic prop they should access. In this case it's the value passed that is dynamic, not the prop key.

Home

Pass the dynamic image values on a standard prop, like `icon`.

```
import firstImage from '../public/images/one.png';
import secondImage from '../public/images/two.png';
import thirdImage from '../public/images/three.png';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ThreePanel
      panelOne={{ icon: firstImage, name: "First" }}
      panelTwo={{ icon: secondImage, content: "Second" }}
      panelThree={{ icon: thirdImage, content: "Third" }}
    />
  )
}
```

ThreePanel

Access the "dynamic" panel prop to pass the specific panel prop object to each `Panel` component. Now the intermediate `ThreePanel` component doesn't need to know much of the deeper nested values, it knows to pass 1 of 3 panel prop objects to it's 3 panel children.

```
export default function ThreePanel(props) {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item>
        <Panel cardData={props.panelOne} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Panel cardData={props.panelTwo} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Panel cardData={props.panelThree} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Panel

Now the passed `carData` prop will be the specific image that was passed from grandparent/ancestor component. Notice here that each individual panel doesn't know which of the 3 panels it is, but it knows it has an image icon prop to access.

```
export default function Panel(props) {
  return (
    <Image
      src={props.cardData.icon}
      height="170em"
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In threePanel.js the panel props should be cardData=props.panelOne, isnt it? Instead of props.cardOne

Comment: Sorry!  That was my mistake.  Variables have been updated.